# My Ethereum smart contract is always returning an empty array when using web3 with metamask

Tags: web3js, contract-development, metamask, contract-debugging

```
import Web3 from 'web3';

window.ethereum.enable();
const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);

const address = "0x977b5A39B6E95A7688570BF1b77e8FAb150791af";
const abi = [
  {
    inputs: [],
    stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
    type: 'constructor',
    constant: undefined,
    payable: undefined,
    signature: 'constructor'
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: 'enter',
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: 'payable',
    type: 'function',
    constant: undefined,
    payable: true,
    signature: '0xe97dcb62'
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: 'getPlayers',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    stateMutability: 'view',
    type: 'function',
    constant: true,
    payable: undefined,
    signature: '0x8b5b9ccc'
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: 'manager',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    stateMutability: 'view',
    type: 'function',
    constant: true,
    payable: undefined,
    signature: '0x481c6a75'
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: 'pickWinner',
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
    type: 'function',
    constant: undefined,
    payable: undefined,
    signature: '0x5d495aea'
  },
  {
    inputs: [ [Object] ],
    name: 'players',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    stateMutability: 'view',
    type: 'function',
    constant: true,
    payable: undefined,
    signature: '0xf71d96cb'
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: 'test',
    outputs: [[Object]],
    stateMutability: 'pure',
    type: 'function',
    constant: true,
    payable: undefined,
    signature: '0xf8a8fd6d'
  }
];

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);

const testMyContract = async () => {
  const manager = await contract.methods.manager().call();
  console.log("manager", manager); // return empty []
  const helloWorld = await contract.methods.test().call();
  console.log("Hello world", helloWorld); // return empty []
}

testMyContract();
```

The address is of the contract deployed to Rinkeby. Whenever I call any method, it always returns an empty array. Even pure functions. I am using Metamask as a provider for web3.

Comment: Is your abi correct? There are a bunch of Object that shouldn't be in a real abi.

Comment: OMG, you are correct. Thank you... basically, I just console.log'd the abi. Using JSON.Stringify instead made the ABI output correctly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer so it helps other in similar situation.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was the abi - it was incorrect, and web3 silently fails. I obtained my ABI by just doing a `console.log(abi)` - which is incorrect. If you are doing it this way, rather do `console.log(JSON.stringify(abi))`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the example from Ethereum & Solidity complete Developer's guide,
this code works: console.log(JSON.stringify(abi))
you have to copy this output from the lottery project and paste it into the lottery-react project lottery.js file and it works.
Thanks @barry